# How to get entire request headers/querystrings in Serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I started to try Serverless framework, but it looks little confusable for some points...
One of them is request headers/querystrings,

I made request template like this:

**s-templates.json**

```
{
  "apiRequestTemplate": {
    "application/json": {
      "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",
      "body": "$input.json('$')",
      "queryParams" : "$input.params().querystring",
      "headerParams" : "$input.params().header",
      "headerParamNames" : "$input.params().header.keySet()",
      "contentTypeValue" : "$input.params().header.get('Content-Type')"
    }
  }
}
```

**s-function.json**

```
  "requestParameters": {},
  "requestTemplates": "$${apiRequestTemplate}",
```

With this setting, I expected to get the request something like this:

```
{
  "body" : {}
  "contentTypeValue" : ""
  "headerParamNames" : ["Accept", "Accept-Encoding", ... ],
  "headerParams" : {
    "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, sdch, br, Accept-Language=ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6", 
    ...
  },
  "httpMethod" : "GET",
  "queryParams" : {
    "category" : "Some Category"
  }
}
```

But in real, what I get is:

```
{
  "body" : {}
  "contentTypeValue" : ""
  "headerParamNames" : "[Accept,Accept-Encoding, ... ]",
  "headerParams" : "{Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch, br, Accept-Language=ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6", ...}",
  "httpMethod" : "GET",
  "queryParams" : "{category=Some Category}"
}
```

This results inconvenient to handle.

I know also, method like below:

**s-function.json**

```
  "requestParameters": {},
  "requestTemplates": {
    "application/json": "{\"category\":\"$input.params('category')\"}"
  },
```

But this is also inconvenient need to specify all parameters in configuration..

Is there any way to get entire request-headers / query-strings as json object in lambda function?

### Modified after answer

I tried to change s-template.json to

```
  "queryParams" : "$util.parseJson($input.params().querystring)",
  "headerParams" : "$util.parseJson($input.params().header)",
```

But result was same...

And, in AWS document, what I want can be seen here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
  "params" : {
    #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
    "$type" : {
      #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
      "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
      #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
      #end
    }
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to set this setting to Serverless framework's s-templates.json...

Answer (score 2):

I use following request template. It will wrap data, path, headers,params,query into a JSON object and pass it to the function.

```
{
    "application/json": {
        "data": "$input.json('$')",
        "path": "$context.resourcePath",
        "method": "$context.httpMethod",
        "headers": "{#foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())\"$header\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))\" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end}",
        "params": "{#foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())\"$param\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))\" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end}",
        "query": "{#foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())\"$queryParam\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))\" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end}"          
    }
}
```

You can refer Apache Velocity Templates to get better understanding about the inner syntax such as `#foreach($header in .....)`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [`$util.parseJson()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)? It takes the json as a string and turns it into a traditional json object.